# Can't read file from server using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to load a file from the server to the database, using phpMyAdmin and MySQL.

Make:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO root;
```

Then trying to get file content

```
LOAD data INFILE '/var/www/goods.csv' INTO TABLE goods'
```

**But I receive an error:**

```
#29 - File '/var/www/goods.csv' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

Comment: Does that file exist on the server? Does the mysql server process user have access to that file?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Edit file name.

Comment: **>> then chown it to the mysql user and the group** Only mysql user?

Comment: This is project directory and can't be with mysql user.